# Handling nested Collections with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, dictionary, optimization, java-8, java-stream

Lately I came across a problem during working with nested collections (values of Maps inside a List):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> items
```

This list in my case contains 10-20 Maps. 
At some point I had to replace value `Calculation` of key `description` to `Rating`. So I come up with this solution:

```
items.forEach(e -> e.replace("description","Calculation","Rating"));
```

It would be quite fine and efficient solution if **all** maps in this list will contain key-Value pair `["description", "Calculation"]`. Unfortunately, I know **that there will be only one such pair in the whole `List<Map<String, Object>>`**.

**The question is:**

Is there a better (more efficient) solution of finding and replacing this one value, instead of iterating through all List elements using Java-8 streams?

Perfection would be to have it done in one stream without any complex/obfuscating operations on it.

Comment: you can create a second map which has all the map keys combined and the index in the list as value, whatever sense that might make.

Comment: Why not just filter before `forEach`?

Comment: @Eugene exactly. I was thinking about something like eg. flattering this collection and using some kind of efficient "find" like functionality. But in my mind was too obfuscated solution...

Comment: @PrzemysławGęsieniec not only obfuscated, but seems really redundant to me

Comment: Since this is a list, you never get anything better than a linear search. If you want to short-circuit after the first match, you can simply use `for(Map<String, Object> m: items) if(m.replace("description","Calculation","Rating")) break;`

Comment: @Holger How does the below answer outperforms the OPs solution. To me both are having Linear time complexity O(n). Any explanation is really appreciated !

Comment: @RavindraRanwala a short-circuiting linear search still is a linear search. Therefore, the time complexity doesn’t change. But stopping after finding the first match is faster than running through the entire list, on average. The time complexity doesn’t tell you, how much time a solution needs. There can be differences between solutions of the same complexity. It’s even possible that a solution with a worse time complexity is faster for a particular input set. The time complexity tells you, how the algorithm will scale when the input data grows really large.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the detailed explanation !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
items.stream()
     .filter(map -> map.containsKey("description"))
     .findFirst()
     .ifPresent(map -> map.replace("description", "Calculation", "Rating"));
```

You will have to iterate over the list until a map with the key `"description"` is found. Pick up the first such, and try to replace.

---

As pointed out by @Holger, if the key `"description"` isn't single for all the maps, but rather the pair `("description", "Calculation")` is unique:

```
items.stream()
     .anyMatch(m -> m.replace("description", "Calculation", "Rating"));
```

Comment: is there something I miss here? why would you first filter and than apply the `replace`, instead if whatever the OP already thought about?

Comment: @Eugene I've used a short-circuiting terminal `findFirst()` which will skip the part of iteration when it finds the first element that meets the condition `map.containsKey("description")`

Comment: @Eugene in OP's approach, the iteration will be continued even after the replacement is done (which is unnecessary since OP know "there will be **only one such pair** in the whole List of Maps")

Comment: oh shoot, should stop thinking about 3 things at a time; but if the maps are relatively small, the advantage of streams and short-circuiting here could be annihilated, but otherwise yes, you are right

Comment: The OP didn’t say that the key `"description"` is unique. The mapping `["description", "Calculation"]` has been said to be unique.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko that is quite clever, to filter it out, and find first matching one. In the worst case, I will be as efficient as with regular foreach. So for sure efficiency is increased. However, there is still in my mind idea of flattering all these maps to one big collection and executing "find" on it. Maybe it is overkill for my purpose but in my mind for long list containing many key-value pairs, such approach of leveraging "find" should work way faster compared to "dumb" iteration. But maybe I'm wrong :(

Comment: @Holger thank you, I like your loop-and-break solution, I borrowed the idea but used `anyMatch` (I hope it's correct even though it's a bit dirty)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko well, you now have a stateful predicate, which is discouraged, which is the reason why I didn’t suggest it. But it’s a pragmatic solution.

Comment: @PrzemysławGęsieniec since you specified the list of maps as starting point, you would need to perform that “merge all maps to one” operation first, which is way more expensive than your single search. Things may be different when you have a lot of similar search-and-replace operations without your list changing in-between (so you can keep your meta lookup object).